# jQuery: loop through comment div and get fields values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to submit users comments via ajax so I'm trying to loop through `<div class="comments-fields">` to get the value of the 2 fields I need.

So far all I'm getting is this error, as if I am not filling the comments textarea which I am.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'comment' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `comments` (`user_id`, `comment`, `parent_id`, `parents`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, , , 0, 2015-10-17 00:57:59, 2015-10-17 00:57:59))

and `console.log(formData)` gives something like this.

```
formData {}
__proto__: FormData
append: append()
constructor: FormData()
__proto__: Object
```

How can I achieve this? if there is a better way please suggest.

HTML

```
 <div class="comment-fields">
     <div class="commenter-comment">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <textarea id="commenter_comment" name="commenter_comment" class="form-control comment-field" title="User's comment" placeholder="Comment Text"></textarea>

         </div>
     </div>

     <div class="commenter-name-email">
         <input type="hidden" id="commenter_parent" name="commenter_parent" class="commenter-parent" value="0">
      </div>

      <div class="commenter-captcha">
          <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-info post-this-comment">Comment</a>
           </div>
       </div>

 </div>
```

The Javascript

```
function commenter_fields(){
    return [
        'commenter_parent',
        'commenter_user_id',
        'commenter_comment'
    ];
}

$(document).on('click', 'a.post-this-comment', function(){
    var formData = new FormData();
    var arrayelem = commenter_fields();
    var elem;
    for(var i=0, size = arrayelem.length; i<size; i++){
        elem = arrayelem[i];
        formData.append(elem, $('#'+elem).val());
    }
    formData.append('per_page', $('.comments_per_page').val());
    var request = $.ajax({ // push question data to server
        type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url         : 'post_this_comment', // the url where we want to POST
        data        : formData, // our data object
        dataType    : 'json',
        processData : false,
        contentType : false
    });
    request.done(comment_done_handler);
    request.fail(comment_fail_handler); // fail promise callback
});
```

I am using PhpStrom, clicking on `FormData()` leads to this file

> C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PhpStorm 9.0\plugins\JavaScriptLanguage\lib\JavaScriptLanguage.jar!\com\intellij\lang\javascript\index\predefined\HTML5.js

And this is `FormData`

```
FormData.prototype.append = function(name,value) {};
FormData = {};
```

Comment: Can you provide the full definition of FormData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [regular objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) because they are much easier to work with over formData (in my opinion).

The jQuery documents state `Type: PlainObject or String or Array` for the data setting in an ajax post which makes me think they like objects too.

So, instead, your click handler could go:

```
var form_data = {
    'per_page': $('.comments_per_page').val()
};

var arr = [
    'commenter_parent',
    'commenter_user_id',
    'commenter_comment'
];

for (var i in arr; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var elem = arr[i];
    form_data[elem] = $('#' + elem).val();
}

// console.log(form_data); // something like => Object {per_page: "some_value", commenter_parent: "some_value", commenter_user_id: "some_value", commenter_comment: "some_value"}

var request = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'your_url_here',
    data: form_data,
    dataType: 'json'
});

request.done(comment_done_handler);
request.fail(comment_fail_handler);
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error with this one. Also doing `console.log(form_data)` results in `Object {per_page: "50"}` only

Comment: I think this works, I had to add `'commenter_comment': $('#commenter_comment').val()` and I started getting values.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach would be to use data attributes on the elements and just build a data string from your values like this:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a.post-this-comment', function () {
    var dataArray=[]; // array to temporarilly store our data
    $('#comment-fields').find('.commenter-field').each(function(i,e){ //loop through all of the fields we need values from, I gave them all the class `commenter-field`
        var $element =$(e); // cache the element
        var type=$element.data('comment-field-type'); // get the name of the data, stored as a data attribute
        var value=encodeURIComponent($element.val()); // get the value, you MUST encode the value, otherwise, you WILL run into issues at some point with illegal chars
        dataArray.push(type+'='+value); // combine the type and value separated by `=`
    });
    var dataString=dataArray.join('&'); // join the array with `&` between each name/value pair
    var request = $.ajax({ // push question data to server
        type: 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url: 'post_this_comment.php', // the url where we want to POST, missing file extension here?
        data: dataString, // our data string
        dataType: 'json', // only if your code expects a json response from `post_this_comment.php`
    });
    request.done(comment_done_handler);
    request.fail(comment_fail_handler); // fail promise callback
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="comment-fields">
    <div class="commenter-comment">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <textarea data-comment-field-type="commenter_comment" class="form-control commenter-field" title="User's comment" placeholder="Comment Text">Some comment...</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="commenter-name-email">
        <input type="hidden" data-comment-field-type="commenter_parent" class="commenter-field" value="some parrent">
        <input type="hidden" data-comment-field-type="commenter_user_id" class="commenter-field" value="some UserId">
        <input type="hidden" data-comment-field-type="per_page" class="commenter-field" value="some number of comments">
    </div>
    <div class="commenter-captcha">
        <div class="col-md-3 text-right"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-info post-this-comment">Comment</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Inspecting the request headers in dev tools shows the below data being sent:

[image]

Comment: I am still getting the same error `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'comment' cannot be null`

Comment: @Halnex Can you please show me your server side code?

Comment: That error means that your schema is set up so that the `comment` field is required but you are not providing a value for that field when you attempt to save your record. If you are seeing the values I showed in the image in your console being sent to the server, you must have an error in your code on the sever that gets the values and calls the SQL